# Deploy Angular Application on AWS S3 or EC2

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I need to deploy an Angular application on AWS,
I found two ways to do it:

1. S3 Bucket
2. EC2 instance using nginx

Which is the best and why?

The application is a big application that will call severals Spring Boot Microservices also deployed on AWS EC2.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to deploy an angular application is AWS S3. The microservices can be hosted on EC2 or any other way it won't affect the angular application.

Plus point in using S3 with Cloudfront distribution is that the application will be loaded faster on the browser and caching by Cloudfront reduces AWS cost significantly.

Deployment over S3 can be also made very easy and faster through aws-cli.